# Copy multiple workbooks to a specific row in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

The below VBA code helps me to import all the workbooks from the specified path to the Master workbook.

The code works perfectly

However,I want to tweak this code a little, so that I can place the code in 5th row of the Master workbook

The below code helps me in placing the data one row below

Can anyone help me to change the code, to paste the data in 5th row of the current workbook.

```
Sub mergeworkbooks()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SLO 23032015")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial


Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the question in two ways.

1. If you want to paste the data 5 Rows below only for the first workbook then try this

I have added a **counter** to count the loop and in the first loop the **Offset is 6 Rows and the remaining loops it is 2 rows**. You could also try something simpler but less cleaner like Before running the for loop `For Each everyObj In filesObj` you could put some text in Range("A5") and that way when it is looking for the last row it will find Row 6 instead of 5. but its a matter of preference. Example `Range("A5").Value = "SomeText"`

```
Sub mergeworkbooks()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim iCount as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SLO 23032015")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

iCount = 1
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
If iCount = 1 then 
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial
    iCount = 0
Else
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial
end if

Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Else if you want a 5 Row Gap for pasting the data between all workbooks then use the below code
I have simply modified the offset in the below line from 2 to 6...
**Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial**

```
Sub mergeworkbooks()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SLO 23032015")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial


Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'am looking for the first code that is ** If you want to paste the data below 5 Rows** . I tried your solution, however it worked for adding 5 rows below in the master workbook after copying from multiple workbooks, but it is giving 2 rows gap in between the workbooks data how to avoid that ?

Comment: To fix that change your `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial` to `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial` I have modified the code above as well. Do run and let me know.

Comment: That works brilliant, you made my day, it works perfectly and you explained the way it works..Thanks a lot :-) Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

You can just activate the cell 5 rows below the current last row. Add this after `bookList.Close` and before `Next`:

```
FifthRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row + 5
Cells(FifthRow, 1).Activate
```